# Creating a sine wave with animated point in OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl

Here's my code currently:

```
void originAxis();
void sineWave();
void idle();


void display()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

originAxis();
sineWave();

printf("%s\n", gluErrorString(glGetError()));
glutSwapBuffers();
}

void sineWave()
{
float wavelength = 2;
float amplitude = 1;
float inc = 0.05;
float k, x, y;
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    for(x=-1;x<=1;x+=inc){
        k = 2 * 3.14 / wavelength;
        y = amplitude * sin(k * x);
        glVertex3f(x, y, 0);
    }
glEnd();

}

void idle()
{
float wavelength = 2;
float amplitude = 1;
float inc = 0.05;
float k, x, y;
for (x = -1; x <= 1; x += inc){
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glPointSize(200);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    k = 2 * 3.14 / wavelength;
    y = amplitude * sin(k * x);
    glVertex3f(x, y, 0);
    glEnd();
}

glutPostRedisplay();
}

void originAxis()
{
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
        glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
        glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
        glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 1);
    glEnd();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 2");

glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutIdleFunc(idle);
glutMainLoop();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here is my output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jyVC.png

Questions:

- Why is my sine wave broken and not continuous?
- I am also getting zero animation, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sine wave is broken because GL_LINES draws a line between two consecutives points you provide, and then between the next two, and so on.

To draw a line connecting all the points you provide, use GL_LINE_STRIP

And there is ~zero animation~ because you are drawing the same thing every frame (didn't really understood your doubt here)

Here is an image I like from Google Images with the primitives types

http://3dgep.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/OpenGL-Primitives.png

Comment: My `idle()` function doesn't seem to be drawing anything at all. How would I go about having a point move along the sine wave?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `glPointSize()` must be called outside the `glBegin(); /*...*/ glEnd();` block =))

Comment: To ~animate~ you must pass different coordinates each frame. The easier way is having at least one variable outside of the function, being incremented every time, serving as a parameter. (if you already have that and I missed, beg your pardon)

Comment: I'm testing with an `idle()` function that is simply

`void idle()
{
 glPointSize(10);
 glBegin(GL_POINTS);
 glVertex3f(0.3, 0.1, 0);
 glEnd();
 glutPostRedisplay();
}`

and it's still not drawing anything?

Comment: I don't know glut very well, but don't you have to do the drawing in the `display()` function? When you call `glClear()` there, it will erase what you have painted elsewhere.

Comment: Yepp, `idle()` is just for incrementing. All sorted thank you.